# Consider A as m by n matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image][image]
I am in a trouble with problem 3. How could I show that? Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: How have you applied the hint?

Comment: I just used LA and made it upper triangular. Actually I am not understanding the question properly.

Comment: https://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~saad/PS/iter3.pdf

Comment: it's another way of writing the normal equations

Comment: I failed to express this. Could you make it more clear. Thank you.